# CSS/PHP: How to make left and right float div the same height regardless of much information is in them?

Tags: php, css

How to make left and right float div the same height regardless of much information is in them? The number of the divs is created dynamically alternating left and right as well as the information in them.

```
<div class="columns">
  <?php
   $cemp = true;
   foreach ( $req_user_emp as $id => $name ) {
     echo "<div ".(($cemp = !$cemp)?" class=\"column_right\"":" class=\"column_left\"").">";
     echo "<h3>".$req_user_emp[$id]['position']."</h3>";
     echo "<h4>".$req_user_emp[$id]['company_name']."</h4>";
     echo $req_user_emp[$id]['description'];
     echo "<div class=\"column_footer\">".$req_user_emp[$id]['start_date']." → ".$req_user_emp[$id]['end_date']."</div></div>";
   }
  ?>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.columns {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.columns:after {
  content: "If you can see this, you broke the columns!";
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -10000000px;
  height: 1px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.row_level {
  display:table-cell;
}
.column_left {
  width: 288px;
  float: left;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.column_right {
  width: 288px;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Now I have some data in MySQL that I want to arrange into this 2 columns. The code works, but if the data in the columns is not equal the the columns are not arranging correctly.
Do you have any idea on how to fix this?
I was thinking also to use a if in the foreach function:

```
 if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
   ENTER_MY_CODE_HERE;
 }
```

and like this to use the the .row_level container for the .left and .right but as far as I know this doesn't work in IE (and I have no way to test it now).

Thank you

Comment: Something like this should do it: [CSS Equal Height Columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Comment: thanks...i like it. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: What about using CSS `max-height` property?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to make all floated elements 100% height. The best approach would be either `height: 100%` or `top: 0; bottom: x;` if the height is known. Otherwise, you're looking at using a visual trick.

Answer (score 0):

you could use 2 solutions:

First JS solution:

```
//equal heights
//usage : matchCols.init('.yourclass');
var compareVal;
var matchCols = {
  init: function(matchClass){
    // reset the start compare value
    var compareVal = 0;
    // get the heightest value
    $(matchClass).each(function(){
      if($(this).height()>compareVal){compareVal=$(this).height();}
    });
    /* set the heightest value */
    $(matchClass).each(function(){
      $(this).height(compareVal);
    });
  }
};
```

or CSS faux columns visual fix:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/